# Delete specific section row from table view

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, stack-overflow

I have two sections in a table view that contains data. When clicking on section 2's delete button it removes all content from the table view. I'm using the table view header for section separation.

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    if section == 0 {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: DiagnosisTVHeaderCell.self)) as? DiagnosisTVHeaderCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.delegate = self
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        return  cell
    } else if section == 1 {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: EMRAttachmentsCell.self)) as? EMRAttachmentsCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.delegate = self
        return  cell
    }
    
    return UIView()
}

func deleteTableCell(index: Int) {
    if attachmentTypeDiagnosis.isEmpty == false {
        attachmentTypeDiagnosis.remove(at: index)
        attachmattachmentInfoDiagnosis.remove(at: index)
        tableviewDiagnosis.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 1)], with: .left)
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(describing: DiagnosisListingTVCell.self)) as? DiagnosisListingTVCell else {return UITableViewCell()}
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.lblTitle.attributedText = "\(self.presenter?.emrRecord?.emrDetails?.emrDiagnosis?[indexPath.row].name ?? "")".style(using: .syne_regular_18_black)
        cell.lblDes.attributedText = "\(self.presenter?.emrRecord?.emrDetails?.emrDiagnosis?[indexPath.row].description ?? "")".style(using: .syne_regular_14_grey)
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: How do you create your table cell from your array ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please update your question with specific details about what should be happening compared to what is actually happening.

Comment: Your problem is unclear. Do you want to delete only one row but for some reason all the rows are deleted?